# Use camera, gallery and files in the same view

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have used Xam.Plugin.Media and Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker to pick photos and files which are working perfectly. Those plugins popup native app when we perform certain operation.
Rather than opening apps separately I would like to make all these options available in a single view.
In that view user can decide what he is going to do, whether taking a photos, picking a photo from gallery or picking a file.
I have attached a [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsitA.png) of this.

Action flow : User click add an attachment button in app. Then this new view will pop up which have all these three options in place. Once user perform an action this view will be closed.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Kaushalya

Comment: It's possible because there are already libraries in native development, and you need to get your albums and files and display them on the UI (with listview or collectionview ...).

Comment: you can read the files from the galary and show it over here in your view and if any file is selected get its path